# Elastic Search Phrase Suggestor - Custom Dictionary

Tags: elasticsearch

I understand that the ElasticSearch phrase suggester can get suggestions for terms based on a field of a document but what happens when that word doesn't exist in the text of a document? Is it possible to hook up the phrase suggester to a custom dictionary in addition to using the text from the document?

Comment: You can just create a document manually inject these values into the same index and same field. Also make sure your search does not consider these documents for search.

Comment: @VineethMohan Many thanks, very clever indeed!

Comment: I have made that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a document manually inject these values into the same index and same field. Also make sure your search does not consider these documents for search.

Comment: I'm just curious is any other way to do it? Perhaps a more slicker document independent approach? Ta

Comment: Everything in Elasticsearch is document based. So i don't think you can inject data outside it.